# Convert Terdata SQL to GCP BG

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert Teradata SQL to GCP BQ SQL

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CAST(CURRENT_DATE/100*100+1 AS DATE),INTERVAL 1 MONTH),INTERVAL -4 MONTH)
    AND DATE_ADD(CAST(CURRENT_DATE/100*100+1 AS DATE),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) - 1)
```

I am getting following error message
No matching signature for operator / for argument types: DATE, INT64. Supported signatures: FLOAT64 / FLOAT64; NUMERIC / NUMERIC; BIGNUMERIC / BIGNUMERIC;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
select 
date_add(date_add(date_add(date_add(date_add(DATE '1900-01-01', interval div(div((extract(YEAR from current_date()) - 1900) * 10000 + extract(MONTH from current_date()) * 100 + extract(DAY from current_date()), 100) * 100 + 1, 10000) YEAR), interval div(mod(div((extract(YEAR from current_date()) - 1900) * 10000 + extract(MONTH from current_date()) * 100 + extract(DAY from current_date()), 100) * 100 + 1, 10000), 100) - 1 MONTH), interval mod(div((extract(YEAR from current_date()) - 1900) * 10000 + extract(MONTH from current_date()) * 100 + extract(DAY from current_date()), 100) * 100 + 1, 100) - 1 DAY), interval 1 MONTH), interval -4 MONTH) add_4_month,
---
date_sub(date_add(date_add(date_add(date_add(DATE '1900-01-01', interval div(div((extract(YEAR from current_date()) - 1900) * 10000 + extract(MONTH from current_date()) * 100 + extract(DAY from current_date()), 100) * 100 + 1, 10000) YEAR), interval div(mod(div((extract(YEAR from current_date()) - 1900) * 10000 + extract(MONTH from current_date()) * 100 + extract(DAY from current_date()), 100) * 100 + 1, 10000), 100) - 1 MONTH), interval mod(div((extract(YEAR from current_date()) - 1900) * 10000 + extract(MONTH from current_date()) * 100 + extract(DAY from current_date()), 100) * 100 + 1, 100) - 1 DAY), interval 1 MONTH), interval 1 DAY) sub_1_month
```